# Custom color in XCode Project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, assets

In order to add a custom color in my project and have it ready for use, is it better to create a new color set in Assets, or create a swift file and add my custom color in a UIColor extension?

I've been told both ways but I wanted to have a reasoned answer.

Comment: Both an color from assets that is also in the extension

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

- If you need a dynamic color with different appearances (light, dark, gamut, contrast etc.) use an asset.
- If you need a simple static color use an extension.